# Material renders as black, but looks fine in textured view?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm working on CG geeks forest road tut. The final render is black and It's a mat problem not a lighting thing like I just thought. In textured view it looks fine. I've attached screenshots. what have I messed up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: As it says in your screenshot, there is no output node in the material. You'll have to add one in the *node editor*

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot, you don't have an *output node* in your material:

[image]

Add one by going to the *[node editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Nodes/Editor)*.

1. To get the nod editor, either press <kbd>F3</kbd> while hovering over an area which you want to make a node editor, or by selecting the area type from the dropdown in the header:

   [image]
2. Then press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Output > Material output* to add an output node:

   [image]
3. Connect the output of your shader to the  *surface* input of the output node:

   [image]