# Object looks fine in material view but black in rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I have referenced [StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18910/material-renders-as-black-but-looks-fine-in-textured-view) post as well as a post from the [Blender Forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20201127144726/https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25974). However, unlike their case, my output node seems fine and I only have one UVMap and thus, I cannot have chosen the wrong UV Mapping as well. Moving the position of the lamp did not help. In addition, I could not find out where the override all materials option is, so, I could not test out that option. As such, I really appreciate your help and thanks in advance for your help.

My .blend file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kx2b5fb4uxfb4t5/animation.blend?dl=0).

Comment: Please add images to your question instead of only adding a file. The relevant information should be included in the body of the question. When adding files, in the future please use [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Thanks.

Comment: @Timaroberts Total Newbie who just started experimenting with Blender yesterday. **Thanks so much** for the input. I will certainly use this platform in my subsequent questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The material of the text is maden by a texture (missing in the .blend file) going into a background node wich feeds the material input (and into the displacement input also).

Background node is intended to be used in the world tab, not the material tab.
I used a diffuse node instead, turned the world to pure black, reduced the lamps intensity to 1000 and assigned a simple wood seamless texture:
this is the result.

[image]

Comment: The animation worked soon after changing material to diffuse BSDF and setting image background. **I wanted to ask what is the difference then between image background and Diffuse BSDF image background.** You mentioned the image for text material missing in .blend file. **I wanted to ask how to add the image into .blend file for future reference as well as how to add nodes since I have fewer nodes (Image texture, Diffuse BSDF and Material Output).**

Comment: Starting form the last question to the first: in the header of the node window (lower part of the window) there is the"add" menu which you can use to add as many nodes as you want; enable the "node wrangler" addon in the preference window, so you'll be able to Ctrl Shift click on a node to see his action. To pack a texture into a .blend file open it in a UV/Image window, go to the header (lower part) and click "Image" and choose "pack".

Comment: The common use of the background node is this: in the header of the node window, after the text menus (view, select, add, node) there are 3 + 3 little icon buttons: press the 5th (world tab). Select the world icon in the properties window (world icon) and press "use node" on the "surface" tab (if it's empty). In this way the background node will act as source of light with color and intensity set by the node himself, wrapping all the scene and at an infinite distance.

Comment: Add an "Environment texture" and plug it in the "color" input and you'll have the basis of IBL (Image based lighting): you can choose an HDRI Image for best results. If you have any other question, please ask them in a new Blender Stack Exchange Question.